# Regex for footnotes in Markdown

Tags: regular-expression

I'm preparing a document in markdown for print and as an EPUB file. I want to remove footnotes for word definitions for the EPUB file.

The foonotes I want to remove are in the format `[mean-X]` where `X` can be any set of alphanumeric characters (including another `-`).

I've tried:

`grep -o "\[\^mean-.*\]"`

Sample results:

```
[^mean-vicissitudes]
[^mean-immortality]
[^mean-ingot]
[^mean-remonstrance]
[^mean-libeller]
[^mean-debauched] and the most amorous[^mean-amorous]
[^mean-turpitude]
[^mean-debauched] drunken, licentious,[^mean-licentious]
[^mean-frivolous]
[^mean-despots]
[^mean-repentance]
[^mean-ignominy]
[^mean-vain]
[^mean-presumptuousness] haughtiness,[^mean-haughtiness]
```

The problem occurs when two or more footnotes appear on the same line, the regex extends to the last occurrence of a `]`.

I've also tried:

1. `grep -o "\[\^mean-.*\][^\[]"` which still had some occurrences like the original along with capturing commas and colons after the last `]`.
2. `grep -o "\[\{1\}\^mean-.*\]"` but it doesn't solve the problem. I thought it would capture only one instance of a `[`.
3. `grep -o "\[\^mean-.*\]\{1\}"` but it doesn't solve the problem either. I thought it would capture only one instance of a `]`.

How can I capture the footnotes using grep and remove them (not replace them with space, but *remove* them)?

P.S. I'm using Git Bash for Windows but I assume the commands will be the same.

Comment: You may also want to take look at `pandoc -t epub -f markdown  -o out.epub`

Comment: `\{n\}` (or `{n}` in ERE) means _n_ instances of the previous item _in a row_, e.g. `a\{4\}` would match `aaaa`. `\{1\}` is not really useful since all the atoms match once by default. `\{n\}` with the opening bracket doesn't affect the later `.*`

Comment: @JJoao, I'm using Pandoc and have created a makefile to cater for PDF and EPUB. It's just that most ereaders have built-in dictionaries, so I wanted to remove footnotes that give word definitions.

Comment: @ Khalid, yes. It makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the `.*` in you expression, which is "greedy".  This makes your expression match the `]` and the rest of the line up to the final `]` on the line. 
 Instead, make this part of the expression match only what you yourself said it may match, i.e. any alphanumeric and `-`.  An alphanumeric is matched with `[[:alnum:]]`, and `[[:alnum:]-]` allows the bracketed expression to match a dash as well:

```
\[\^mean-[[:alnum:]-]*\]
```

Running this on the data in your question:

```
$ grep -o '\[\^mean-[[:alnum:]-]*\]' file
[^mean-vicissitudes]
[^mean-immortality]
[^mean-ingot]
[^mean-remonstrance]
[^mean-libeller]
[^mean-debauched]
[^mean-amorous]
[^mean-turpitude]
[^mean-debauched]
[^mean-licentious]
[^mean-frivolous]
[^mean-despots]
[^mean-repentance]
[^mean-ignominy]
[^mean-vain]
[^mean-presumptuousness]
[^mean-haughtiness]
```

Your `grep` command will obviously *extract* the matches, but won't remove them.  To do that, use a `sed` editing script:

```
$ sed 's/\[\^mean-[[:alnum:]-]*\]//g' file





 and the most amorous

 drunken, licentious,





 haughtiness,
```

Add to this some removal of empty lines and of initial whitespace,

```
$ sed 's/\[\^mean-[[:alnum:]-]*\]//g; /^[[:blank:]]*$/d; s/^[[:blank:]]*//' file
and the most amorous
drunken, licentious,
haughtiness,
```

Or, to only modify the lines that had a `[^mean-...]` on them,

```
sed '/\[\^mean-[[:alnum:]-]*\]/{ s///g; /^[[:blank:]]*$/d; s/^[[:blank:]]*//; }' file
```

Comment: or just grab everything but the closing `]` with `\[[^]]*\]`?

Comment: @ilkkachu That's another option, but I used what I used because the user was explicit about what was allowed after the `mean-`.  Also, we don't know if there is other markup within brackets that should _not_ be removed.

Comment: an intermediate `\[\^mean-[^]]*\]` could be useful...